# Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I'am getting below error:

> [Fri Aug 18 14:31:50 2023] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in
> /home/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258

Laravel version is 8 and PHP version is 8

I have tried below commands too:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer update
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer guys, change on public/index.php file

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

this to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

slash is problem

Comment: by default, it's ``$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`` unless you modified it for some reasons !

Comment: Yep this error due to many reasons, example php version changable and etc. I get error on this line so...